# Color temperature or effective temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, astrophysics, thermal-radiation, stars

I am a high school student interested in astronomy and physics, and I am trying to understand the difference between color temperature and effective temperature of a star. As I have searched this forum, I noticed that this question has been asked before, but I have yet to find a clear and comprehensive answer. Can someone please explain the distinction between these two concepts, and how they relate to the study of stars? Additionally, I would like to know which of the two temperature measures is considered more precise in the field of astronomy.

Answer (score 1):

Color temperature refers to the temperature of the star if we fitted a blackbody curve to only measurements of its visible light spectrum (i.e. the $400 - 700$ nm range).

However, if we gathered data about much shorter wavelengths of EM radiation (like UV) from that same star, we *could in theory* find that it deviates from our already fitted blackbody curve for visible light. For example, this challenges our assumptions of the photosphere's physics - there could be some degree of absorption in the photosphere that we didn't anticipate.

If we then try a better blackbody fit against both the UV and the visible wavelength measurements, we can estimate what the "effective" temperature of the star actually is (which provides a better estimate of the "actual" temperature of the star)